# "chmod u+w config.txt" results in "Operation not permitted."

Tags: config.txt

I am trying to use `chmod` to allow me to change `config.txt`.  I am using NOOBS on the Raspberry Pi Zero.

```
chmod u+w config.txt
```

results in "Operation not permitted."

Comment: What config file is this? What does `ls -l` say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo chmod a+w config.txt
```

Explanation:
You don't say much about the file (who owns it?) or which user you're running the command as, but I guess you're probably logged in as a normal user and the file is owned by someone else (root?).  Hence you don't have permission to change the permissions.

Using `sudo` runs the command as the `root` user, who has permission to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

definitely sudo to fix the permissions issue.

You could also use: sudo chmod 600 config.txt (assuming you are the only user who needs to read/write.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod for more details.